# How to add custom policy to device administrator api?

Tags: android, device-admin

In list of policies provided by android OS there exist policies about password , wipe data and etc . Is it possible to add new policy in this list?
I need a policy when a mobile connect to a BTS It checks if it's cell id is in my list of valid BTS cell ids .

Comment: That would require creating your own custom version of the OS, rolled into a custom ROM to deploy to your specific device.

Comment: How I can do this ? creating my own custom version of the OS

Comment: Which parts of AOSP I should change?